# How do I get multiple Modal instances to properly function in one page?

Tags: javascript, modal-dialog, babeljs, hugo

I'm creating a team page with modal popups for bio.

I'm using Hugo with Babel JS as the framework. There is no bootstrap on this project.

HTML

```
<div class="team-ui">
{{ with .Params.executive_team }}
   {{ range . }}
      {{ partial "components/modalTeammate.html" . }}
   {{ end }}
{{ end }}
</div>

{{ with .Params.executive_team }}
   {{ range . }}
      {{ partial "components/modalTeammateBio.html" . }}
   {{ end }}
{{ end }}
```

modalTeammate.html

```
<div class="teammate-card trigger" data-id="#myBio-{{ .modal_id }}" data-toggle="modal" data-target="myBio-{{ .modal_id }}" id="trigger">
    <img src="{{ if .img_overwrite }}/uploads/headshot-{{ .img_overwrite }}.png{{ else }}/uploads/headshot-{{ .name }}.png{{ end }}" alt="{{ .name }} | {{ .job_title }}" loading="lazy" class="teammate-img">
    <p class="teammate-name">{{ .name }}</p>
    <p class="teammate-jobtitle">{{ .job_title }}</p>
</div>
```

modalTeammateBio.html

```
<div class="modal myBio-{{ .modal_id }}" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true" id="myBio-{{ .modal_id }}">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-body">
            <div class="bio-box">
                <div class="bio-box-sidebar">
                    <img src="{{ if .img_overwrite }}/uploads/headshot-{{ .img_overwrite }}.png{{ else }}/uploads/headshot-{{ .name }}.png{{ end }}" alt="{{ .name }} | {{ .job_title }}" loading="lazy" class="teammate-img">
                    <p class="teammate-name">{{ .name }}</p>
                    <p class="teammate-jobtitle">{{ if .job_title_long }}{{ .job_title_long }}{{ else }}{{ .job_title }}{{ end }}</p>
                </div>
                <div class="bio-box-content">
                {{ with .bio }}
                    {{ range . }}
                    <p class="has-margin-bottom-half">{{ .p }}</p>
                    {{ end }}
                {{ end }}
                </div>
                <button class="modal-close is-large" aria-label="close"></button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Current JS

```
var modal = document.querySelector(".modal");
var trigger = document.querySelector(".trigger");
var videoID = trigger.getAttribute('data-id');
var closeButton = document.querySelector(".modal-close");

// YouTube Player API Reference
var tag = document.createElement('script');

tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

var player;
function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
    player = new YT.Player('player', {
        height: '390',
        width: '640',
        videoId: videoID
    });
}

function toggleModal(e) {
    if (!modal.classList.contains("is-active")) {
        modal.classList.add("is-active");
        player.playVideo()
    }
    else {
        modal.classList.remove("is-active");
        player.pauseVideo()
    }
}

function windowOnClick(e) {
    if (e.target === modal) {
        toggleModal();
    }
}

trigger.addEventListener("click", toggleModal);
closeButton.addEventListener("click", toggleModal);
window.addEventListener("click", windowOnClick);
```

I know I'm missing something, but I'm not sure what else I can do.

I'm using this oringal code as an example and a base.

```
<a href="#" data-id="{{.Get "youtube"}}" class="button is-warning trigger" data-toggle="modal" id="trigger">Watch the Video</a>
<div class="modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-body" id="player">
            Content
        </div>
    </div>
    <button class="modal-close is-large" aria-label="close"></button>
</div>

<script src="/js/modal.js"></script>
```

Comment: var modal = document.querySelector(".modal"); only selects the first modal. You need to use querySelectAll for modal and trigger, so that you each trigger open the corresponding modal.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll